# Can't get this.props inside child componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

In my app.js I'm authenticating with firebase and saving the user in the state and sending as props to Home component.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            user:{}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.authListener();
    }

    authListener() {
        fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if(user) {
                this.setState({user});
            } else {
                this.setState({user:null});
            }
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                {this.state.user ? (<Home user={this.state.user} />) : (<Login />)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Then in my Home.js

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            registered: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>Home</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The **console.log(this.props)** returns an empty user:

```
{user: {…}}
```

The weird thing is that if I only **console.log(this)**, I get the whole object, including the user with all the info.

```
Home {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, state: {…}, …}
context: {}
props: {user: Lk}
refs: {}
state: {error: null, registered: false}
updater: {isMounted: ƒ, enqueueSetState: ƒ, enqueueReplaceState: ƒ, enqueueForceUpdate: ƒ}
_reactInternalFiber: FiberNode {tag: 2, key: null, type: ƒ, stateNode: Home, return: FiberNode, …}
_reactInternalInstance: {_processChildContext: ƒ}
isMounted: (...)
replaceState: (...)
__proto__: Component
```

Why can't I access this.props inside the componentDidMount ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `componentDidMount` is called initially with an empty `user` (*an empty object*). You only set it to `null` after the authentication check.

So, `this.state.user` will evaluate to `true` initially due to

```
this.state={
        user:{}
    }
```

If you set your initial state to have `user:null` it will work since the `Home` component will only get mounted when a user exist.

---

So the flow is, the `Home` component is mounted with an empty `{}` `user` and the `componentDidMount` is run logging an empty `user` prop. Then, when you authenticate, the component does **not** run `componentDidMount` because it is already mounterdit is only re-rendered with the new props.

Answer (score 0):

due to official doc

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will
>   trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser
>   updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will
>   be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate
>   state. Use this pattern with caution because it often causes
>   performance issues. In most cases, you should be able to assign the
>   initial state in the constructor() instead. It can, however, be
>   necessary for cases like modals and tooltips when you need to measure
>   a DOM node before rendering something that depends on its size or
>   position.